# Asp.Net and jquery-ui: reference to not existing file requested on page

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, reference, bundling-and-minification

I am currently facing the problem that on one of my pages, the page requests a file named "jquery-ui-1.11.1.**min**.js" which causes a 404 file not found error. This is because the correct file name is "jquery-ui.**min**-1.11.1.js". So, for some reason, something uses wrong jquery references.

My MasterPage has the following references (among others):

> ```
> <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true">
>   <Scripts>
>      <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
>      <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
>      <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
>   </Scripts>
> </asp:ScriptManager>
> ```

What I have tried:

- Clean/rebuild the solution
- Remove/Re-install jquery-ui with NuGet
- Search for the wrong reference in the project (nothing found)

Another way of solving this would be to simply add a copy of the JS file and rename it so that it matches the requested file's name. But then again, this is a very dirty solution because it doesn't solve the root cause of problem.

The missing file causes problems like not-working datepicker, etc. I have temporarily solved it by putting this on top of the page:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min-1.11.1.js") %>'></script>
> ```

However, this is terrrible to maintain, so I would like to have the following things:

- A working way to reference ALL jQuery stuff in the ScriptManager on the MasterPage (jQuery-2.1.1, jQuery-ui and jquery-ui.css). With the current references, only jQuery-2.1.1 seems to work.
- Find and eliminate the one that requests the wrong "jquery-ui-1.11.1.**min**.js" file

To me, bundling is still a blackbox and I couldn't find any usable solution to include everything that jQuery needs onthe MasterPage. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked in `_references.js`? to check if it's referenced in there

Comment: I don't have this file in my solution. I believe this is because I'm not using MVC, but Web Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the problem. The following line in BundeConfig.cs was the reason for the wrong request:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

This apparently also included the "min" version of jquery-ui.

My solution for bundling jquery now is:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                         "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

This solves the maintainability issue and causes all pages that use the Site.Master to correctly use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Using NuGet, add the

```
AspNet.ScriptManager.jQuery.UI.Combined
```

package.

Then confirm that

```
<asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
```

is in your Site.Master Scripts section